# What are the pros and cons of Unit Test vs. GUI automated End-to-End test

Tags: unit-testing, project-management, automated-tests

if you project have only a limited time budget, will you invest your team's time writing none-Gui unit test or GUI automated End-to-End test script?For me, i prefer gui-automated end-to-end test because it can simulates the actually operations of the user.

Comment: but for a variety of project,the internal api changes frequently(which makes great portion of unit tests fail) while user interface remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, converted it to an answer.  I had a lot to say, and it addressed your implied question: "what are the pros and cons of writing high level automated end-to-end tests, vs automated unit tests?"

Comment: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do” is listed in the FAQ as something not to ask.  Even as a question, this doesn't sound like a "practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that you face".  It sounds like you already have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The advantages of writing automated E2E UI tests, instead of unit tests**

You don't have to be as familiar with the specific implementation, or even how coding works to write automated UI tests.  Many tools allow you to just click record, perform some actions, and save a script.

You are also going to find a lot more user-impacting bugs up front, because you are working directly with the application at the user's perspective.

**The disadvantages of writing automated E2E UI tests, instead of unit tests**

Automated end-to-end tests are not nearly as maintainable as true unit tests.  Same with GUI tests, as the GUI is the most likely part of a program to change in a way that breaks existing automation.

It is also a lot easier to get 100% code coverage in automated unit tests, and you are less likely to be duplicating logic in each test.  If you get one test failure, it is more likely to correspond to a specific piece of code.  Conversely, if you have one break in code, it is less likely to cause more than one test to fail.

At this level, you are more likely to be able to address strange corner cases that you would never see if you weren't interacting with the code directly.

It is also much harder to set up a machine to automatically run your tests in a more integrated environment.  With true isolated unit tests, you can run them on your dev machine, or even your build machine, as they should have absolutely no dependencies or impact on the box they are running on.

**Strategy**

I would personally prefer to get the developers to write the unit tests, so the test team could focus on higher level test automation.

You should also consider load/perf/security/fuzz testing.  They are inherently higher level, are hard if not impossible to test by hand, and give a great bang for the buck for test automation (hours-to-severity wise).  They also are the least likely to require work from scratch, since there are dozens of existing tools that you can leverage.

Comment: thanks! sadly,our team is quite small,each developer has to write script to auto test aother developer's module.

Comment: @auottest: If you don't have a test team, you should at the least host some bug bashes (with small prizes/free dinner), and get non-programmers into the mix.  It's fun for the whole team, and you'll find a lot of E2E bugs that way.  Try to do this at a middle-of-the-road milestone, rather than at the end of the project.

Comment: @auottest: One more thing.  I don't really have a way to segue it into my answer, but you may find it easier to write unit tests for code that implements [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) :)  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

A unit test is one where it can test the functionality of each and every method of your implementation. The main reason for doing a unit test is to give the developer the confidence in making changes to the codes, knowing that changes in one place is not affecting other places or cause anomaly to working codes.

In your situation, you may want to gauge whether you see maintenance value in your project(i.e. you will get the maintenance phrase contract), if you do, you may wish to place more emphasis on unit tests.

Unit testing is one surest and definitive way of giving assurances to change requests and bug fixes. :D

Comment: +1; good addition.  My answer doesn't really say why you want automated regression tests to begin with (whether unit tests, or e2e tests).

Answer (score 1):

This video [compares different types of testing techniques.](http://www.eventhelix.com/agile/unit-testing.htm#An_Introduction_to_Unit_Testing)

Unit testing is preferrable as:

- The act of developing unit tests encourages good design
- Unit tests are a lot easier to write that UI tests
- A failed unit test exactly pinpoints the source of the problem

Comment: +1 "A failed unit test exactly pinpoints the source of the problem"

Answer (score 0):

Set yourself as a scrum-like team, identify a product owner (who would represent customers) and come up with Definition of Done for each of the story on the table.

That will help you to balance time investments as the team members will be clear on what they need to do in order to have stories/tasks done. Let them self-organize and come up with the right strategy in regard Unit tests and E2E tests.

As long they meet the DoD - they are hitting right balance...

Unit tests are quite different from E2E tests - different skills are required to develop them etc. Both of them are equally important and it is not easy cut to say where to invest (and where to 'cut conrners') - it depends on the nature of the product that your team builds - you might be able to manage it.

I think running it like a scrum team (agile) - review and adapt often - will help you to hit right balance.